# I can’t find my minecraft files in Windows 10 with Linux

Tags: windows-10, minecraft

There’s something wrong with my Windows boot. But before I reinstall Windows 10, I need to backup my Minecraft saves with Linux.

So I use Linux live USB mount into Windows system disk, but I can’t find my `.minecraft` folder! The folder should be in `Local/Users/Andare/AppData/Roaming`. There’re many other folders. But I didn’t find `.minecraft`. And I tried to search `.minecraft`, but I got no results! Could the folder be hidden?

Answer (score 0):

In Linux files and folders which begin with a dot are indeed hidden. To show these hidden files one has to press `Ctrl-H` when in the concerning folder. This toggles show/hide hidden files.